# C#. p12 contains two certificates. How to get them?

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, pkcs#12

I have a p12 certificate that contains several certificates. How to get a collection of these certificates?

Code:

```
new X509Certificate2(bytes, pass);
```

returns last. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of
[Importing all certificates contained in a .p12 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656324/importing-all-certificates-contained-in-a-p12-file)

You might want to consider searching a little harder ;-)